# Does a bridge always necessitates creating an intermediate token?

Tags: tokens, exchanges, liquidity-provider, decentralized-exchange

When one creating a so-called **bridge** in order to exchange a coin on one blockchain to a coin on a different blockchain, how does it work?

Does it **always necessitate** creating an intermediate token - LT - issued by a DEX?

A scheme is:

```
user A:
   send KSM → receive INTermediate token, 1:1
```

then

```
user B:
  send SOL → receive KSM
```

then

```
user A:
  send INTermediate token → receive SOL
```

In all the steps the tokens that get sent and received, sent and received from and to a smart contract of a DEX. Right?

Does it work this way?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit confusing as you seem to be describing to different process. One being a transfer of token from one blockchain to another and the other being exchanging one token for another. When you use a bridge to send one token to another blockchain, there's no intermediate token. If you send KSM from native blockchain A, you will receive a representative token for KSM on blockchain B backed 1:1 by the real KSM tokens.